# Formato de millones tras suma de valore formateados toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, json, numberformat

Tengo una tabla que lleno con un webservice, con una columna de valores que mayormente son millones (no siempre).
A la columna le di formato .toLocaleString("es-AR") y se ve ok.

Pero hace que el formato del total de la columna, que calculo con una función, se simplifique en menos dígitos. Por ejemplo el total sin formato me da= 132,731000000002 (millones), con .toLocaleString(“es-AR”) me queda 132,73

Necesito que se muestre de esta manera= 132.730.000,25

```js
$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'milink/data2.json',
    success:function(response){
        myArray2 = response
        buildTable2(myArray2)
        console.log(myArray2)
    }
    })
                              
                          
                              
function buildTable2(data){
    var table2 = document.getElementById('myTable2')
        
        table2.innerHTML = ''
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var row = `<tr>
                    
                    <td>${data[i].Codigo}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].Nombre}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].Cantidad}</td> 
                    <td>${data[i].Cantidad_Mensual.toLocaleString("es-AR", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})}</td> 
                    <td>${data[i].Promedio_Mensual.toLocaleString("es-AR", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})}</td> 
                    <td>${data[i].Compra_Anual.toLocaleString("es-AR", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2})}</td> 
                    </tr>`
        table2.innerHTML += row
    }
        var table2 = document.getElementById('myTable2'), sumVal = 0;
        
            for (var i = 0; i < table2.rows.length; i++)
            {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table2.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML);
            }
            document.getElementById("val2").innerHTML = "" + sumVal.toLocaleString("es-AR", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
            console.log(sumVal);

           
        }
```

Comment: No entendí. ¿Cuál es el valor *exacto* que estás recibiendo en `Compra_Anual`?

Comment: Hola @Pollo , gracias por interesarte. Los valores de la columna Compra_Anual los traigo del json del webservice y van variando día a día. En mi html les doy el formato .toLocaleString.  Y abajo los sumo. Y esa suma me la muestra con el formato de millon simplificado (132,73), pero necesito que no lo simplifique, que muestre el numero completo(132.730.002,05).  Si yo le saco el formato toLocaleSting a los datos de la culumna, me muestra  132.730.002,05 completo.

Comment: A cada valor recibido, (1) lo estás agregando como texto en la tabla (2) estás leyendo ese texto de cada fila de la tabla (3) convertís el texto en número para sumarlo (4) sumás ese número.... ¿Por qué no sumarlo directamente en el paso (1) apenas obtenés el dato? El error está en `parseFloat()`, ya que así como está no va a interpretar bien el `.` del separador de miles del formato de número argentino... pero es completamente innecesario estar convirtiéndolo desde texto a número, cuando originalmente lo tenías como número.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a ofrecer una idea de solución a tu problema, que no es **la óptima** pero ha sido pensada para que aprendas algunas **características básicas** de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

la solución óptima es emplear la función `Intl.NumberFormat()` ver: [Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat/format)

Supongamos que el valor que deseas presentar una vez calculado se encuentra en la variable `total` que contiene un entero (positivo o cero) seguido de una coma y una parte decimal, pues usas una **localización hispana**. Como la parte decimal puede contener hasta doce dígitos (eso muestras) sólo se usarán los primeros 8 para ofrecer las respuestas con céntimos.
Te ofreceré una función de formateo a fuerza bruta utilizando algunos atributos y métodos de las cadenas.
En el código se comenta lo necesario.

```js
function formatearMillones(total){
   // convierto a cadena para formatear el valor
   var totsinformato = ''+total;
   if(totsinformato.indexOf('.') > -1){ // si usa locales hispanos poner ','
      // declaro algunas variables que voy a necesitar
      var chunk, millares, unidades, centimos, millones, total; 
      // Parto el valor ingresado por el separador de decimales
      chunk = totsinformato.split('.');
      // como los ceros a derecha en expansiones decimales carecen de 
      // significado agrego suficientes para tomar una cadena de ocho
      chunk[1] += '00000000';
      // y extraigo los 8 dígitos a usar para millares, unidades, y centimos
      // los dos primeros en bloques de tres y el último bloque de 2.
      millares = chunk[1].slice(0,3);
      unidades = chunk[1].slice(3,6);
      centimos = chunk[1].slice(6,8);
      // notar que slice(posicion_inicial, posicion_siguiente_al_ultimo_a_extraer); 
      //console.log('chunk[1]='+chunk[1] + ' millares='+millares+' unidades='+ unidades + ' centimos='+centimos);
      // verifico que haya millones
      if(parseInt(chunk[0]) > 0){
         // Aplico módulo 3 a chunk[0] para formar el mayor bloque significativo
         // de los millones y aplico un ciclo while para construir los demás
         var lenmillones = chunk[0].length;
         var extremo = lenmillones % 3;
         if(extremo == 0){ extremo = 3; }
         millones = chunk[0].slice(0, extremo);
         // si quedan digitos sin usar en chunk[0] los paso a millones
         // separando con puntos
         if(extremo < lenmillones){
             var posterior;
             while(extremo < lenmillones){
                posterior = extremo + 3;
                millones += '.' + chunk[0].slice(extremo, posterior);
                extremo = posterior;
             }
         }
         total = millones + '.' + millares + '.' + unidades + ',' + centimos;
      }else{
         // si no hay millones el total inicia con el mayor bloque significativo no nulo
         if(parseInt(millares) > 0){
            total = ''+ parseInt(millares) + '.' + unidades + ',' + centimos;
         }else if(parseInt(unidades) > 0){
            total = ''+ parseInt(unidades) + ',' + centimos;
         }else if(parseInt(centimos) > 0){
            total = '0,' + centimos;
         }else if(parseInt(unidades) > 0){
            total = '0,0';
         }
      }          
      return total;
   }else{
      return totsinformato + '.000.000,00';
   }
}
let test1 = 43;
let test2 = 132.73000025; // Uso punto decimal en lugar de coma porque los
                          // locales aquí son del mundo inglés
let test3 = 44567132.73001025;
let test4 = 0.07301025;
let test5 = 0.00001025;
let test6 = 0.00000805;
let test7 = 0.00000025;
let test8 = 0.00000005;
console.log(formatearMillones(test1));
console.log(formatearMillones(test2));
console.log(formatearMillones(test3));
console.log(formatearMillones(test4));
console.log(formatearMillones(test5));
console.log(formatearMillones(test6));
console.log(formatearMillones(test7) + ' No es lo deseado');
console.log(formatearMillones(test8) + ' No es lo deseado');
```

Si se observan los valores devueltos por los tests test7 y test8 que resultan desagradables se puede concluir que el método de formato ofrecido tiene límites superior e inferior debido a que valores muy grandes o muy pequeños dan lugar a redondeo y notación exponencial.
Esto debe resolverse verificando antes de empezar si `if(totsinformato.indexOf('e') > -1){ //hacer algo para el caso }` pero, dudo que te vayas a enfrentar a esos valores. Y mi objetivo de mostrarte cómo usar funciones de cadena para presentar valores numéricos **como uno los quisiera** está cumplido. Si necesitas algo más puedes partir de aquí para obtenerlo.

### Referencias:

- [Métodos útiles con cadenas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods)
- [Matemáticas básicas en JavaScript — números y operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Matem%C3%A1ticas)
- [Tomando decisiones en tu código — condicionales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals)
- [Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat/format)